# Phone number validation using onblur seems to get in a loop

Tags: javascript, onblur

I am using the `onblur` attribute to call a Javascript phone number validation function.  However, if the format of the number is invalid, after displaying an error message using `alert()`, when I click on the OK button the message is repeated immediately instead of focus being returned to the phone number field to allow me to correct the format.  It's impossible to get out of the loop.

This is the code for it:

```js
function validPhone(phoneNum)
  //  check for valid phone numbers in the format 999-999-9999
  {
    var strPhone = phoneNum.value;
    var rePhone = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/;
    var blnResult = true;

    if (strPhone.length !== 0 && (strPhone.length !== 12 || strPhone.match(rePhone) == null)) {
      blnResult = false;
      phoneNum.select();
      alert("Phone number is invalid.  Please try again.");
      phoneNum.focus();
    }
    return blnResult;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="homephone" size="12" onBlur="validPhone(this)"></input>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this?  It is not working in Chrome or the Apple browser, but for some reason it works in IE 11.

Comment: Why not just use the `<input pattern="/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/>"' and then tap into the HTML5 validation framework? You are reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove phoneNum.select() and phoneNum.focus().

Thoose instructions make fired a onBlur events, and you are in a loop with no end ...

You should turn your size attribute into maxLength.